# Prevent Visual Studio Code taking new line when editing HTML tag attributes

Tags: html, word-wrap, visual-studio-code

I have an annoying issue when editing HTML in VS Code. If I have an element say a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="myBtn" style="width: 50%"></button>
```

When I hit a certain number of characters on a line of code with a tag and start typing more characters into that line e.g

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="myBtn" style="width: 50%">Click here</button>
```

VS Code will automatically separate the line and spread the tag across two lines like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="myBtn" 
style="width: 50%">Click here</button>
```

I like to keep code files short when I can and this can be quite annoying when this happens as there is plenty of space on the original line above. I have tried disabling word wrap in settings, set the wrap line length for HTML to 0 etc. but the behaviour persists. How can I completely disable this from automatically happening?

Comment: Are you using prettier or another formatter?  Try disabling them and see if you get the same behaviour.

Comment: @Mark turns out that was the case. Had the same idea as you did and went to investigate my extensions and found word wrapping settings within them. Working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. It was to due to my extensions. Prettier and rewrap (which I only thought was for comments) were the culprits here. No more auto rewrap happening anymore.

Comment: For me it was specifically rewrap (I also have both). I recommend confirming that yourself and editing the answer.